Daylight savings is affecting adding a day to a Date
So I am trying to add a day to a date however I think daylight savings is causing me issues, here is the code:
  let date = new Date('2024-03-31');
  console.log(date);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  console.log(date);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  console.log(date);

and the resulting logs:
 LOG  2024-03-31T00:00:00.000Z
 LOG  2024-03-31T23:00:00.000Z
 LOG  2024-04-01T23:00:00.000Z

Would using UTC dates fix this issue? Something like this:
  const date = new Date('2024-03-31');
  let utcDate = Date.UTC(
    date.getUTCFullYear(),
    date.getUTCMonth(),
    date.getUTCDate(),
    0,
    0,
    0,
  );
  utcDate += 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
  let nextDate = new Date(utcDate);
  nextDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);


What do you want to do exactly? Add a day in UTC?

Using UTC may avoid the problem, but eventually you have to convert back to the user's timezone and may get surprising results.

@Ghost I want to add a day to a date without encountering problems like those seen in the console logs i posted

@Barmar is there a surefire way of adding a day to a date and not being at risk of errors?

If the current time is 02:30 on the day before the clock moves ahead, what should the result be? The clock jumps from 01:59 to 03:00 the next day, so there is no 02:30.

Likely a duplicate of How can I add 1 day to current date? The issue here is that the method employed adds 1 to the local date, but the results are being printed as UTC. In places where daylight saving is observed, the day going into DST is shortened, while the day going out is lengthened by the offset (usually 1 hour but in some places 30 minutes).
